# Parsing dates in node.js: moment.utc() is not returning the correct UTC unix time

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, unix, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to parse a date string and return the corresponding unix time to midnight at the start of the date in the UTC zone. However, my node.js keeps returning the unixtime at the start of that date in MY timezone.

What am I doing wrong? This should print 1440633600 to the console but it prints a number corresponding to the unix time in my timezone, not UTC.

```
    var moment = require('moment');
    var datestring = "August 27 2015";
    var unixDate = new Date(datestring);
    var myDate = moment.utc(unixDate);
    console.log(myDate.format('X'));
```

"datestring" will not always contain a "Z" at the end (which indicates UTC) but it might sometimes, so I can't just add a "Z" before parsing. There's got to be something I'm missing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

`var myDate = moment.utc(datestring, 'MMMM DD YYYY');`

**The explanation:**

`var unixDate = new Date(datestring);` with `datestring` set to `"August 27 2015"` will set `unixDate` to the timestamp corresponding to midnight on August 27 2015 in your time zone.

Subsequently, `var myDate = moment.utc(unixDate)` sets `myDate` to a `moment` object set to that same time. Since you are sending it a timestamp and not a date, it has no reason to adjust for timezone. Since you generated the timestamp based on the time in your timezone, that's what `moment` sees.

One fix is to change that line to `var myDate = moment.utc(datestring, 'MMMM DD YYYY');`. Since `moment` will be getting a string to process rather than a UNIX timestamp, it will select midnight on August 27 2015 in UTC.